# Acting state on pauli matrix and problem with dimension

Tags: operators, hamiltonian

I define local hamiltonian as:

$ H_{\Omega_{k}}=\frac{\mathbb{1}- \sigma^{z}}{2} \frac{\mathbb{1}- \sigma^{z}}{2} \in M_{2{\times}2}
$
where $\sigma^{z}$ is pauli operator.

And prepare the state:

$|\psi\rangle=\left|x_{1} x_{2} \ldots x_{N}\right\rangle .$ In the case that $\left\{x_{j}\right\}$ is a assignment $0, 1$

I have a problem with this notation:

$H_{\Omega_k}\left|\psi\right\rangle$

Because $H_{\Omega_K}$ is matrix $2 \times 2$ but $\psi$ don't have $2 \times 1$ dimension.

Can you show me why it's make sense?

Comment: It does *not* make sense. Why did you invent this confused situation? Also note that that your product of two projection operators $P=(1-\sigma_z)/2$  is equal to just one of them:  $P^2=P$. You do not need two factors. One will do

Comment: @mikestone I am assuming they mean to have a tensor product between them, so that this is a sloppily written Ising model.

Comment: Where did you find this notation, can you link/screenshot?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.3931 I find notation in this paper

Comment: Section mapping SAT to ising

Comment: In the paper, the $\sigma$s have subscripts. That means it selectively acts in the part of the wavefunction that is $2\times1$

Comment: So in equation (6) page 7, formally, there should be $\otimes$ between the $\frac{(1-\sigma^z_{j_1})}2$ and $\frac{(1-\sigma^z_{j_2})}2$?

Comment: I haven’t read the paper. But generally in Ising model we have nearest neighbour spin interaction. So maybe something like $(\mathbb{1}\otimes \mathbb{1}…\otimes S_{j1}\otimes\mathbb{1}\otimes …)\cdot(\mathbb{1}\otimes\mathbb{1} …\otimes S_{j2}\otimes\mathbb{1}\otimes …)$ where $S$ is given by the $\sigma$ thing.